# VB - Wait for Object Creation

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to follow the example for externally access a RhinoScript module from Excel (in my case Excel 365 on Windows 10) using a standard method.

```
Dim Rhino As Object
Dim RhinoScript As Object

Set Rhino = CreateObject("Rhino4.Application")
Set RhinoScript = Rhino.GetScriptObject()
```

But I'm running into a "Runtime 424 - Object Required" error on the last line.

The problem seems to be that GetScriptObject isn't waiting for CreateObject to fully complete because while Rhino4 starts up, the UAC of Windows 10 will prompt me to allow the Updater to make changes to the system before allowing it to bring up the GUI.  If I debug these statements and go line-by-line so Rhino4 has time to fully start before GetScriptObject hits, everything works fine.  So, is there a ways to make GetScriptObject wait until Rhino4 is completely started? I've tried setting up a loop that check's Rhino's value (Nothing?), but it immediately falls through.  I'm a little new to VB, so apologies for what may be a newbie question.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: can you add a reference to rhino from vba to allow any insight into the automation of it?

Comment: by the looks of this some API programming is needed https://github.com/dalefugier/TestVbAutomation   and http://4.rhino3d.com/5/rhinoscript/introduction/external_access.htm.  I agree with @Mat's Mug, you'll have to loop the error not the nothing status, I'd add a retry count into the mix to, just in case, say 100000 attempts, and a small delay using the sleep api before retry.

Comment: I didn't see the link to the external access page, @Nathan_Sav.  I was only using the .chm help file that came with Rhino3D.  Thank for the reference.  Hopefully this will help solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know nothing of the Rhino API, there *may* be a better way to do this.

If you *know* that the run-time error is caused by what you're describing, and that `Rhino.GetScriptObject` is *eventually* going to succeed, you can loop until it works:

```
Dim iterations As Integer 'max value: 32,767
Do
    iterations = iterations + 1 'will *eventually* overflow if loop keeps failing
    On Error Resume Next 'switch off error handling
    Set RhinoScript = Rhino.GetScriptObject
    On Error GoTo 0 'restore error handling (IMPORTANT!)
    If Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 424 Then Err.Raise Err.Number ' rethrow
    Err.Clear
    DoEvents ' so that the host app remains responsive while the loop runs
While RhinoScript Is Nothing
```

Notice the re-raising of the error if the number is anything other than the expected 424; this is to (try to) prevent an infinite loop if the situation is hopeless.

[Nathan made a good comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984357/vb-wait-for-object-creation#comment71148239_41984357) about adding additional protection against infinite looping - here by incrementing a counter until its value overflows its type (raising runtime error 6). You could also use a constant and an `If` check, if 32,768 iterations is too long a timeout.

Probably not the best solution, but *should* work. Ideally you would explore the Rhino4.Application API, see if it exposes any member that could be used to determine if the instance is "ready" to use. `IsReady`, or `State` perhaps.

Comment: Yes, both you and @Nathan_Sav provided useful feedback.  Thanks for the pointers.  Hopefully this will resolve my problem.  The original code was done for Rhino v3, on XP and Excel 2010, so stuff like UAC wasn't a problem.  Windows 10 and Excel 365 seems to have gummed up the works :p.